# Auto Layout Suggestions

Tags: ios

[image]

If I have a view controller like the one above and I am trying to position the views inside of the prototype cell, what is the proper way to place constraints on those labels and view?

I originally put the `3 sets, label, label, label` labels into one stack view. Then the `1,2,3` labels into another stack view. Then put those two stack views into a final stack view. Then I placed constraints on the top, left, right, and bottom of the final stack view containing the other two stack views. When I ran the app only the Food Items label and the 1px height view was showing and the other stack views were not showing up at all.

Does anyone know how to fix this with correct constraints or give me a starting point?

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Please add an image that actually shows the constraints (with their values) and also an image showing what is happening at runtime. If you want to debug this first then `1)` use the visual debugger and check what the constraints are being set to and `2).` preview your interface using the built-in preview assistant editor: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/PreviewingYourUserInterface.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010215-CH47-SW1

Comment: Hello I have attached an image of what shows up after I run the app. Can you please take a look at it! Thank you!

Comment: Still not enough info. All the image show is that your constraints are wrong. See steps `1` and `2` from my previous comment. And you need to add a list of constraints with their values.

Comment: Oh ok let me try that